# Using ConcatRelated() To combine older data rows into newer rows

Tags: ms-access, vba, concatenation, jet-sql

### Access(2013) SQL

I am using ConcatRelated()\Dlist (sometimes I refer to Visual Objects that are sourced) to handle a few task with the table below. I can combine data based on a matching key though what i would like to do is combine data based on a matching key and a value that i would use to determine which record is newest. This way the old row gets abandoned and the new row receives the Concat.

What I can do.

### Table Main

```
Ticket   |     Name       |    Code2     |  LastHop |
------------------------------------------------------
DBC123456       James          10101010     Mexico
DBC123457       James          10101010     Texas
DBC123459       James          10101010     Texas
DBC123457       Mike           10101011     Texas
DBC123459       Mike           10101011     Virginia
```

### OutPut

```
Table Main
Ticket                        |     Name       |    Code2     |  LastHop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DBC123456,DBC123457,DBC123458        James          10101010     Mexico
DBC123457,DBC123459                  Mike           10101011     Texas
```

What I want to do
'Find duplicate Code2
'Remove DBC from respective TicketNumber 
'Compare the 6 digits from the now stripped ticket to see which one is higher 
'Keep the highest ones row information and add all the "OLD" Ticket numbers to the Highest ones

This way I always have the most up to date data and a track of the old Ticket Numbers

I.E

```
Ticket                        |     Name       |    Code2     |  LastHop |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
DBC123459,DBC123456,DBC123457       James          10101010     Texas
DBC123459,DBC123457                 Mike           10101011     Virginia
```

### Current Code

```
SELECT
    sub.[Name],
    sub.Code2,
    sub.LastHop,
    DList("Ticket",
        "Query3",
        "[Code2] = '" & sub.[Code2] & "'",
        "Ticket")
        AS Ticket
FROM
    (SELECT
    q.[Name],
    q.Code2,
    q.LastHop
    FROM Query3 AS q
    GROUP BY
    q.[Name],
    q.Code2,
    q.LastHop
 ) AS sub
ORDER BY
    sub.Code2;
```

### Thank You!

Comment: Is DList function a MS ACCESS built in function?

Comment: In MSACCESS you can write, in plain VBA, any function you like, and use it in your query! This way you don't have to straggle with SQL subtle syntax.